# What is the equivalent to JAR file META-INF/MANIFEST.MF for a JIMAGE file?

Tags: java, java-module, java-platform-module-system

I work primarily with *Scala*, which up until now has been most compatible with *Java* 8. However, I've been kicking the tires of *Java* 11, and one particular element of the switch to modules has intrigued me ...

When dealing with a library packaged in a *JAR* file, it's fairly straightforward to retrieve information about it by examining the standard attributes in the embedded `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` file, such as the *implementation* and *specification vendor, title & version*, etc. (OK, so that file, or some of these attributes, may be missing, but they're typically available for what I use.)

However, it seems that the new *JIMAGE* format explicitly forbids the use of a `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` file. (See this [bug report](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8060458) as one example.)

Is there a way to specify and retrieve the corresponding information for a library packaged in a *JIMAGE* file? In particular, I would like to both define and obtain the equivalent values for the following standard manifest attributes:

- `Implementation-Title`
- `Implementation-Vendor`
- `Implementation-Version`
- `Specification-Title`
- `Specification-Vendor`
- `Specification-Version`

Comment: Pardon my ignorance. What is _JIMAGE_ ? Google didn't find anything.

Comment: @Abra Try this [Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=java+"jimage")...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The jimage format is only used internally, to store the class files that are part of the JDK.  It’s not a general format for packaging libraries and is not available for use outside of the JDK.

Comment: Hi Mark, thanks for taking the time to reply.

I seem to recall seeing somewhere that it is possible to create a custom JIMAGE that includes user code and resources, as well as the JDK. Is that possible? If not, are there any plans to open the use of this format up for user libraries in future?

If it *is* just the JDK that is included, then I guess that I can retrieve equivalent information from the system properties, so that would resolve that problem. However, it would be nice if there was a single mechanism for retrieving that kind of information, given a class type reference.

Comment: There’s no support for using the jimage format outside of the jdk, and there are at present no plans to add such support.

If you use the `jlink` linking tool to create a custom JDK image and provide your own code in the form of explicit modules then your code will be stored in the internal jimage file in the resulting JDK.  The file itself is divided up into modules and each module can carry its own resources, including `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` if you like.

Comment: Great. Thanks for the clarification!